Игра — в парах или по парам? В чём разница?
Если играют несколько команд, в каждой из которых по 2 человека, то это игра в парах или по парам? И есть ли вообще разница?
Кажется, что при "игре в парах" разные пары не взаимодействуют друг с другом (например, так можно играть в шахматы за разными досками), а выражение "игра по парам" лучше подходит для ситуации, где в одной общей для всех игре участвуют и соревнуются друг с другом несколько команд из 2 человек.
Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я не прав.

Короче, в словарях пишут в таких ситуациях так  (БСЭ):

Шахматы (от перс. шах мат — властитель умер), игра специальными фигурами на 64-клеточной доске для 2 партнёров...

То есть игра для двух партнёров, ну или участников, что по сути то же, что партнёров, скорее всего...
Если же пары взаимодействуют друг с другом, то пишут "парные игры" — парный теннис, например.
Команда — это люди, участвующие на одной стороне, то есть называть соперников командой — неверно. Составляется турнирная сетка или таблица, и каждый участник играет сам за себя, то есть каждый в своей команде. Этапы можно называть игры турами.
Если же пара людей прыгают вместе в мешке, и это действительно команда, то командная пара... Наверное, игры в парах, тоже можно.
Турнирная игра для пар участников — мне кажется, так.
Если же "игры по парам", ну как разговорный вариант сойдет, вероятно, но возможно придётся объяснять, что имеется ввиду.

Я бы так сказала: игра парами, игроки делятся по парам

Делятся по парам - да, игра по парам сомнительно.

Да, все верно: предлог ПО – распределительный при глагольном управлении, а Т. п. парами – инструментальный падеж, обозначает способ или характер действия; играть парами и игра парами.
